# Is field complete with respect to zero ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I' confused about completeness of a field.

Let $K$ be a field. Let $I＝0$ is zero ideal of $K$, which is maximal.

Then, $K\rightarrow\varprojlim_{n\geq 1}K/I^n$ is isomorphic, so $K$ is complete with respect to $I$.

But then, no sequence converges as long as we use the definition of Caucy sequence of module.

What am I missing?

Comment: The constant sequences converge.

Comment: The $I$-adic topology of course depends on $I$, and you simply defined the discrete topology on $K$.

Comment: Usually, completeness of a field refers to **algebraic** completeness of.a field. This is entirely different from topological completeness.

Comment: *But then, no sequence converges as long as we use the definition of Caucy sequence of module.* Not by the normal definition of Cauchy sequence. What definition are *you* using?